# How to expose a class to the global scope with esbuild?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bundler, esbuild

**Update**

user @TKoL suggested defining a property in the window object. This produces the result I wanted to achieve, although I do not know if it is the correct way to proceed. I will be using this method for the time being. Thanks!

---

I am using [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) in my project (first time using a bundler / developing JS in this "style").
The project is a small web component for which I developed a class that the end user should be able to utilize in their scripts.

```
// this is the component, which is then bundled and minified by esbuild.
// i have omitted various imports required in the class here.

export default class Widget extends HTMLElement {
    /// code here is not relevant
}

customElements.define('custom-widget', Widget);
```

As it stands, the end user is able to utilize the widget from HTML like this:

```
<custom-widget some-custom-attribute="some-value"></custom-widget>

let widget = document.querySelector('custom-widget');
widget.someMethodDefinedInTheClass();
```

However, I would like to allow the user to do it all via JavaScript as well.

How can I make **esbuild** expose the **Widget** class to the global scope? I'd like to do this to enable behaviours such as:

```
let wOptions = {}; // object of initialization options for the widget
let widget = new Widget(wOptions);
someContainer.append(widget);
widget.someMethodDefinedInTheClass();
```

Comment: you can add a property to the `window` object, `window.myFunction = ...`

Comment: damn, that was simple. Thanks, I was stuck on this for a while haha.

Comment: Maybe you can teach me something in exchange then. Where do i go to find out how to extend an HTML Element like that and do cool stuff with it? that seems interesting

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've been reading here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components and following online tutorials for web components.

Answer (score 3):

To make any way bundled js file to expose anything to the global scope you  have to set it as a property of [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) object (that represents the global scope) like

```js
globalThis.Widget = Widget;
```

`globalThis` keyword is a best way to use global object in javascript because it works the same on browser page, nodejs or service worker environment. If your code will be only executed on browser page you can also use `window` keyword.

Comment: Today I learned about `globalThis`, thanks for that, I'm probably going to use this for the rest of my life.